# Can i show imageurl that exist in a library as a column?

Tags: column, url, picture-library

I got a picture library.I store the images. There are image urls. I want to reach these urls as a column. Is there a way to show them as a column?

Answer (score 0):

none out of the box but you could do this by creating a hyperlink column and pasting the link from the image into it.

Upload the image and save it, then open the image properties and right click > copy shortcut to capture the direct link to the image. then paste the link into the hyperlink field you added to the library.